# Using Requirements Authoring Starter Kit (RASK) with Word 2007 and TFS 2008

Tags: tfs, requirements

The [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537171%28office.11%29.aspx) describes how to use Word 2003 to manage requirements along with the work items in TFS using RASK (Requirements Authoring Starter Kit) . I am wondering If It is applicable with Word 2007 and TFS 2008/2010. If It is, could somebody provide some links for the same. I can't afford to use other third party components as they are very expensive.

EDIT :- http://vstfs2010rm.codeplex.com/ is a good place to start. I am reading that now.

Comment: If you were going to use RASK with TFS, you would at the least want to modify it to leverage [Content Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157891.aspx) which were introduced in Word 2007 after RASK was built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Requirements Authoriing Starter Kit is really old. As you have found, there have been some more recent efforts in this area.

The ALM Rangers have created guidance for managing requirements in the past: [Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server Requirements Management](http://vstfs2010rm.codeplex.com/).

They also have a project that they are working on at the moment:

> **Word Plug-in for TFS (TFSWP)**
>   The vision of this project is to support the communication between the non-technical users, who prefer Word as requirements elicitation tool, and the developer persona. Bidirectional link between Word and TFS work item tracking is a typical example but as usual, all details will be defined by the project team.

For more details, see the ['tfswp' tag on Willy's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/tags/tfswp/).

You might also want to take a look at this project on CodePlex:

> **TfsWord - Word Extensions for Team Foundation Server**  TfsWord allows
>   you to create and edit TFS work items
>   using Microsoft Office Word 2007.
>   TfsWord complements the Microsoft
>   Office integration built into Team
>   Explorer, adding work item editing
>   capabilities to Word.

For more details, see http://tfsword.codeplex.com/

The premier paid solution is TeamSpec from Team Solutions:

> **TeamSolutions TeamSpec** provides a rich project requirement management
>   experience directly inside Microsoft
>   Word. By making Team Foundation Server
>   (TFS) project artifacts such as
>   Scenarios, QOS Requirements, Risks,
>   Issues, Bugs, Tasks, among others,
>   first class citizens inside Microsoft
>   Word, TeamSpec enables Application
>   Lifecycle contributions by the
>   Business Analyst, Project Manager, and
>   Executive roles.

For more details, see http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/teamspec-features.aspx